# Find variance from 2 variances of 2 datasets with difference sizes

Tags: statistics, variance, mean

In an attempt to find the mean number of hours his tutorial classmates spent per day preparing
for tutorials, John collected data from 10 of his friends in the tutorial group and found that the
mean is 2.4 hours with a standard deviation of 0.8 hours. However, a day later he felt that the
sample size is too small. So he collected data from another 5 of his friends and found that the
mean is 2.0 hours with a standard deviation of 1.2 hours. Find the mean and standard deviation
when these 2 sets of data are combined.

Please help, thank you

Comment: This seems like a homework question, what steps have you tried already and where do you get stuck?

Comment: I hope following link will help you https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55999/is-it-possible-to-find-the-combined-standard-deviation

Comment: thank you all, just got stuck in standard deviation things